# Move item with underlying text in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to move an item together with underlying text in a structural way?

```
* Header
** Subheader
   some text
```

I want to move `Subheader` **together with** `some text` in a **structural** way.  So I tried `M-UP/DOWN` when I'm on Subheader but it only moves the Subheader not the "some text" as well.

Note: I prefer not to cut paste yank text as it's not structural.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `org-cut-special` (bound to `C-c C-x C-w`), `org-copy-special` (bound to `C9c C-x M-w`) and `org-paste-special` (bound to `C-c C-x C-y`):
they are analogous to Cut/Copy/Paste but they operate on subtrees.

Also, you might try looking at the Org menu when you are editing an org-mode file. The above commands and quite a few more are under the `Edit structure` menu.